# What are the steps to build a production-based HF blockchain network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

What are the main steps to be able to work with production-based networks?
For now, I'm able to build a simple network with 2 orgs, 1 or 3 orderers and invoke/query transactions by using the terminal on my localhost. What should it be my next step? Trying to run this network on Cloud or I'd still have to do something more before taking this step?

P.S: I'm working with Hyperledger Fabric to develop blockchain networks.

Comment: Do you want to build a production network with some other participants and run some Dapp on it? The question is very broad, the network turns into a production network when any kind of real value is being put there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.